# sencha touch generating app issue

Tags: macos, extjs, sencha-touch, osx-lion, sencha-touch-2

I am generating app using sencha touch with Sencha touch Cmd. I am using this syntax `sencha generate app MyApp Path/to/folder all`. But what this does in it creates this project in my sencha touch sdk folder. Why and how I can make a project somewhere else?

Below is the output of my command

```
Zafars-MacBook-Pro:secha-touch-sdk zafarsaleem$ sencha generate app /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/playoutube/www all
Sencha Cmd v3.0.0.250
[INF]       init-properties:
[INF]       init-sencha-command:
[INF]       init:
[INF]       -before-generate-workspace:
[INF]       generate-workspace-impl:
[WRN]       Ignoring @require ../version/Version.js in js/String.js
[WRN]       Ignoring @require ../Ext-more.js in js/Format.js
[INF]       -before-copy-framework-to-workspace:
[INF]       copy-framework-to-workspace-impl:
[INF]            [copy] Copying 1103 files to  /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/senchatouch/secha-touch-sdk/all/touch
[INF]            [copy] Copying 1 file to /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/senchatouch/secha-touch-sdk/all/touch
[INF]            [copy] Copying 1 file to /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/senchatouch/secha-touch-sdk/all/touch
[INF]       [propertyfile] Updating property file: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/senchatouch/secha-touch-sdk/all/.sencha/workspace/sencha.cfg
[INF]       -after-copy-framework-to-workspace:
[INF]       copy-framework-to-workspace:
[INF]       -after-generate-workspace:
[INF]       generate-workspace:
[INF]       init-properties:
[INF]       init-sencha-command:
[INF]       init:
[INF]       -before-generate-app:
[INF]       generate-app-impl:
[INF]           [mkdir] Created dir: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/senchatouch/secha-touch-sdk/all/app/model
[INF]           [mkdir] Created dir: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/senchatouch/secha-touch-sdk/all/app/controller
[INF]           [mkdir] Created dir: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/senchatouch/secha-touch-sdk/all/app/store
[INF]           [mkdir] Created dir: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/senchatouch/secha-touch-sdk/all/app/profile
[INF]           [mkdir] Created dir: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/senchatouch/secha-touch-sdk/resources/icons
[INF]       Generating new packager.json file using native packager
[INF]       copy-sdk:
[INF]            [copy] Copying 1 file to /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/senchatouch/secha-touch-sdk/all/resources/css
[INF]       -after-generate-app:
[INF]       generate-app:
```

Answer (score 1):

I dont know about mac, but in windows this is how we create app in desired location. I think the problem lies with the path you are setting.

```
#  Make sure the current working directory is the Sencha Touch 2 SDK
cd /path/to/sencha-touch-2-sdk
sencha app create MyApp /path/to/www/myapp
```

Comment: This command is for Sencha Touch command tools. I am using Sencha Touch Cmd. Command tools are no longer compatible with Sencha Touch 2.1. According to official documentations, my command is correct but it is not working for me.

Comment: http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/guide/command_app Read the first comment at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into several problems with Sencha Touch because the official documentation is not applicable to versions 2.1+.

After struggling, my help came from [this site](http://senchatouchdev.com/wordpress/2013/03/04/sencha-touch-2-1-1-getting-started/).